# Lock entire mysql database from hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm

I want to lock entire mysql database from hibernate, I mean put in a read mode all the tables. Something like:

```
FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
```

And then unlock the database, always through hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO this approach is not desirable. After acquiring a read lock on all tables (which can be easily done by parsing the `information_schema.tables` table), subsequent attempts to write in the database will be held until they time out.

Besides, all locks acquired by a session are released at the end of the session. The locking session would need to be kept active in order to keep the locks.

As an alternative, I would recommend revoking write permissions to the user the application connects as. To do it, please refer to [this previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18105688/1446005). Or perhaps you can have two users, one with all privileges, one with only read privileges. When you want to put your application in read-only mode, just switch users.